# image randomisation Eclipse Java Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

Currently having issues with using one button to randomise two image views within eclipse android, I have managed to randomise one imageview using the one button but cant figure out how to randomise both imageviews with the one button.

I have this code so far:

```
import java.util.Random; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 

public class randomIMG extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


private Integer [] mImageIds = { 
R.drawable.img_one,
R.drawable.img_two,
enter code hereR.drawable.img_three,
R.drawable.img_four,
R.drawable.img_five,
R.drawable.img_six,
};


private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
private ImageView iv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_IMG);

Integer q = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setImageResource(q);

View nextButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private static final Random rgenerator2 = new Random();
private ImageView ib;



public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
Integer p = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];
iv.setImageResource(p);
break;
}

}

}
```

Any help would be great cheers.

Comment: I didn't get what   issue do you have

Comment: currently have 2 image view boxes & one button. When the button is pressed I want a random image to be generated into each of the image boxes. Not just one box. it is currently happening in only one box one image is changing & randomising whereas the other box is not randomising

Comment: ok, but all the code you need is in place. You just missed the findViewById for the other `ImageView`, `ib` I suppose, and, on click you have to do what you are already doing for `iv` to `ib`

Comment: I've tried to do what you said but errors returning could you write the code that you are referring too please

Comment: would you mind post the stacktrace of the exception you got?